# SQL query, 2 tables, avoid duplicated results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Table 1

NO_REG - ID

Table 2

NO_REG - BAGS

the problem its that table 1 contains lets say 3 ID, table 2 has the same NO_REG but just 1 row in BAGS

i do

`SELECT BAGS, ID FROM TABLE 1 AS T1 INNER JOIN TABLE 2 AS T2 ON T1.NO_REG = T2.NO_REG`

**I get**

```
NO_REG    ID - BAGS
123       999- 2
123       989- 2
123       979- 2
```

**I need**

```
NO_REG    ID - BAGS
123       999- 2
123       989- NULL (or 0)
123       979- NULL (or 0)
```

hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Why don't you know which rdbms you are using? sql-server != mysql Regarding your question, how do you know which id goes with which bag? What if there are two records in Table2? What if there are more records in Table2 than in Table1 having the same id? Please be more clear about such edge cases, especially since what you want is really inconventional.

Comment: What are the values in NO_REG?

Comment: sorry forgot about that, updated the post.

Comment: Is there a third table? How do you know that BAG 2 belongs to ID 999? What is the rule for that? Any other specific rules? And have you found out yet whether you are using MySQL or SQL Server? :)

Comment: im using sql server, just 2 tables `NO_REG(invoice #), ID(products), BAGS(bags used to dispatch those products)` the problem its that the bags are duplicated per product(ID) line.

Answer (score -1):

You need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` which retrieves matching values and null for non matching

Just something like

```
SELECT BAGS, ID FROM TABLE 1 AS T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE 2 AS T2 ON T1.NO_REG = T2.NO_REG
```

Comment: This is not true. Changing inner join to left join doesn't magically turn the given results to the desired results, not even using DISTINCT.

Comment: But I think @Olvathar may on the right track for what the OP means rather than is actually saying.  I suspect the 3 IDs are not actually all 999.

Comment: @GolezTrol that's not magic. The sample shown of what is needed points to the solution given. As danny said the 3 ID may not be the same

Comment: If what you say is true, then the first output would output only 1 record instead of 3. The fact that you get a BAG for every ID, means that there are already matching records, so changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN won't change that. It *might* result in more records, but the records you already got remain the same.